# closing a socks/proxy connection in python

Tags: python

I am writing some code that uses poplib and imaplib to collect emails through a proxy server.

I use the following to set up a proxy connection:-

```
import socks
import socket
socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS4,proxy_ip,port,True)
socket.socket = socks.socksocket
```

Which I got from the stackoverflow post:-

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3386724/python-how-can-i-fetch-emails-via-pop-or-imap-through-a-proxy
```

Then I make my connection with the email server:-

```
server = poplib.POP3(self.host, self.port)
server.user(self.username)
server.pass_(self.password)
```

I am testing my code in a unittest and have encountered a problem that I believe relates to my connection with the proxy not closing down properly.

An example is:-

I have set up the proxy connection and am trying to establish a connection with the email server. As part of the unittest I intentionally use an incorrect email server password.
The poplib library throws an exception that it can't connect. I catch the exception in the unittest, then move on to the next unittest, trusting the poplib library would properly close my previous connection.

My understanding is that this is not a good thing and that I should be ensuring the email and proxy server connections are properly closed.

I know how to close the pop3 connection:-

```
server.quit()
```

But do not know how to close the connection with the proxy server or if I have to do so.

Could someone please help me with this question or with my understanding if that's where the problem lies :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No special action is required. When you close the POP connection, the proxy connection will close automatically, since it's only needed while you are connected to something through the proxy.

Comment: Thank you very much for your relpy, that is what I was hoping.