# Work with imap and pop3 servers, via proxy

Tags: python

Is it possible to run multiple simultaneous thread with different proxy settings?
I need to work with imap and pop3 servers, via proxy. I trying use `socks.setdefaultproxy`, but it set default proxy for all active threads.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. But you will have to be more specific about what you are doing and the libraries you use.

Comment: I fetch email using imaplib and poplib libraries.

Comment: Look at these: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6400197/539465 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/3387230/539465 . They don't do monkey-patching, so you can use a different proxy for each connection.